# Django render ModelForm with ajax response

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I need to render a django modelform with the response of an ajax call.

What I actually do is:

I call an ajax function giving the model_pk = 0 to return me an empty form

```
$.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
    data: {'ubi_pk':0},
    type: 'POST', // GET or POST
    url: '{% url 'ubicacion_obtener_form' %}',
    success: function(response,status) { // on success..
        if (status == 'success'){
            $('#form-nueva-ubicacion').html(response);
        }
        ...
    },
    ...
});
return false;
```

this is my view:

```
def ubicacion_obtener_form(request):
    try:
        ubi_pk = request.POST.get('ubi_pk',0)
        if ubi_pk!='0':
            ubi = Ubicacion.objects.get(pk=ubi_pk)
            ubicacion_form = UbicacionForm(request.POST,instance=ubi)
            form = render_to_string('ubicacion_form.html', {'ubicacion_form':ubicacion_form},
                                        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        else:
            ubicacion_form = UbicacionForm(request.POST)
            form = render_to_string('ubicacion_form.html', {'ubicacion_form':ubicacion_form},
                                        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        return HttpResponse(form,status=200)
    except Ubicacion.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse(u'No existe la ubicación',status=400)
    except Exception as e:
        return HttpResponse('%s %s' % (e.message,e.args),status=500)
```

This is the `ubicacion_form.html` template:

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% csrf_token %}
{{ubicacion_form|crispy}}
```

When I give the ajax function an ID, my view should return the form with the data of the Model, with the fields with the data, BUT, when I try to get an empty form, it return me the form with "form errors", with those messages of *necessary fields and those horrible red colors.

What am I doing wrong? How can I get an empty form without the error messages?

**NOTE** I am using `crispy_forms` to render my forms with bootstrap theme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're still passing in `request.POST` when instantiating the supposedly-empty form in the else clause. Don't do that: just do `ubicacion_form = UbicacionForm()`.

Comment: You are right, I knew it was a simple thing but I can't find the right way. Thank you!